# with nginx, how to redirect part of request to apache

Tags: redirect, nginx

### Some solutions about redirection can be found. But what I want to do is redirecting part of requests to another server, specifically, only when a request url includes string "service". For example:

http://localhost/service/image-------------> http://localhost:8080/service/image

http://localhost/service/image/upload------> http://localhost:8080/service/image/upload

http://localhost/service/blog--------------> http://localhost:8080/service/blog
.....
.................................................................................................................................................................
but blow will still served by ngnix,cause no "service" included within url

http://localhost/wiki/....

http://localhost/video/....

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use location regex matching together with proxy_pass, example:

```
upstream apache {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

# in your server block:

server{

  # location matching is prioritized by accuracy and order of definition

  location ~* ^/service {
    proxy_pass http://apache;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

`^/service` will match any request beginning with `/service` and forward it to Apache.

`proxy_pass` is transparent for the user, i.e. it will forward the request to Apache and return the output to the user.

For more info on location matching, checkout http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: `location ~* ^/service/(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://apache/$1;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }`
--------------------------------------------------------------------thx,after a litter modification as above,everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
location / {

    if ($request_uri ~* "^/service/.*") {
        rewrite ^ http://localhost:8080$request_uri permanent;
    }

}
```

P.S. did not check

Comment: user973254:your solution doesn't work,got error:301 Moved Permanently,somebody tells me "proxy pass" is needed,actually,he said:"just put the proxy pass inside a location that matches the type of URI you want to proxy".I am not sure whether I have understood this,so tried like this:http://pastebin.com/dxebv9fz, got same error as before.